# Sign in to Nodejs web app, using Azure AD

Tags: node.js, azure, authentication

I'm trying to figure out how you can authenticate users using Azure AD. In order to experiment, I tried the example from Microsoft, found at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-node-webapp-openidconnect.

I've set up an Active Directory in Azure, and added a new application called *test* with add id uri: http://testmagnhalv.

Now, when I run the server, following the instructions in the readme, I get redirected to login.microsoftonline.com and promted to log in. But when I provide username/pw, I get redirected back to the login page again.

I suspect the problem is that I don't set the variables in the config.json correctly, but I'm having a hard time finding documentation for what values need to be set.

Anyone got any experience with this example?

Comment: have you tested my proposed solution?

Answer (score 5):

At first you must to add your app to active directory then use [ADAL (Active Directory Authentication Library) for nodeJS](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/releases)

```
npm install adal-node
```

prepare your app for authentication referencing azure AD App registration values.

```
var AuthenticationContext = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;

var clientId = 'yourClientIdHere';
var clientSecret = 'yourAADIssuedClientSecretHere'
var redirectUri = 'yourRedirectUriHere';
var authorityHostUrl = 'https://login.windows.net';
var tenant = 'myTenant';
var authorityUrl = authorityHostUrl + '/' + tenant;
var redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000/getAToken';
var resource = '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000';
var templateAuthzUrl = 'https://login.windows.net/' + 
                        tenant + 
                        '/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=' +
                        clientId + 
                        '&redirect_uri=' + 
                        redirectUri + '
                        &state=<state>&resource=' + 
                        resource;
```

Now you need to get authorized with the token.

```
function createAuthorizationUrl(state) {
  return templateAuthzUrl.replace('<state>', state);
}

// Clients get redirected here in order to create an OAuth authorize url and redirect them to AAD.
// There they will authenticate and give their consent to allow this app access to
// some resource they own.
app.get('/auth', function(req, res) {
  crypto.randomBytes(48, function(ex, buf) {
    var token = buf.toString('base64').replace(/\//g,'_').replace(/\+/g,'-');

    res.cookie('authstate', token);
    var authorizationUrl = createAuthorizationUrl(token);

    res.redirect(authorizationUrl);
  });
});
```

And finally handle the auth redirection

```
// After consent is granted AAD redirects here.  The ADAL library is invoked via the
// AuthenticationContext and retrieves an access token that can be used to access the
// user owned resource.
app.get('/getAToken', function(req, res) {
  if (req.cookies.authstate !== req.query.state) {
    res.send('error: state does not match');
  }

  var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);

  authenticationContext.acquireTokenWithAuthorizationCode(
    req.query.code,
    redirectUri,
    resource,
    clientId, 
    clientSecret,
    function(err, response) {
      var errorMessage = '';
      if (err) {
        errorMessage = 'error: ' + err.message + '\n';
      }
      errorMessage += 'response: ' + JSON.stringify(response);
      res.send(errorMessage);
    }
  );
});
```

You can find the full example, and more here in ADAL for nodeJS repository:

[Windows Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for Node.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs)

This is a [simple but full demo](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/blob/master/sample/website-sample.js) taken from GitHub ADAL repository

#### website-sample.js

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var logger = require('connect-logger');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('cookie-session');
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');

var AuthenticationContext = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;

var app = express();
app.use(logger());
app.use(cookieParser('a deep secret'));
app.use(session({secret: '1234567890QWERTY'}));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('login');
});

/*
 * You can override the default account information by providing a JSON file
 * with the same parameters as the sampleParameters variable below.  Either
 * through a command line argument, 'node sample.js parameters.json', or
 * specifying in an environment variable.
 * {
 *   "tenant" : "rrandallaad1.onmicrosoft.com",
 *   "authorityHostUrl" : "https://login.windows.net",
 *   "clientId" : "624ac9bd-4c1c-4686-aec8-e56a8991cfb3",
 *   "clientSecret" : "verySecret="
 * }
 */
var parametersFile = process.argv[2] || process.env['ADAL_SAMPLE_PARAMETERS_FILE'];

var sampleParameters;
if (parametersFile) {
  var jsonFile = fs.readFileSync(parametersFile);
  if (jsonFile) {
    sampleParameters = JSON.parse(jsonFile);
  } else {
    console.log('File not found, falling back to defaults: ' + parametersFile);
  }
}

if (!parametersFile) {
  sampleParameters = {
    tenant : 'rrandallaad1.onmicrosoft.com',
    authorityHostUrl : 'https://login.windows.net',
    clientId : '624ac9bd-4c1c-4686-aec8-b56a8991cfb3',
    username : 'frizzo@naturalcauses.com',
    password : ''
  };
}

var authorityUrl = sampleParameters.authorityHostUrl + '/' + sampleParameters.tenant;
var redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000/getAToken';
var resource = '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000';

var templateAuthzUrl = 'https://login.windows.net/' + sampleParameters.tenant + '/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>&state=<state>&resource=<resource>';


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/login');
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.cookies);

  res.cookie('acookie', 'this is a cookie');

  res.send('\
<head>\
  <title>FooBar</title>\
</head>\
<body>\
  <a href="./auth">Login</a>\
</body>\
    ');
});

function createAuthorizationUrl(state) {
  var authorizationUrl = templateAuthzUrl.replace('<client_id>', sampleParameters.clientId);
  authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl.replace('<redirect_uri>',redirectUri);
  authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl.replace('<state>', state);
  authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl.replace('<resource>', resource);
  return authorizationUrl;
}

// Clients get redirected here in order to create an OAuth authorize url and redirect them to AAD.
// There they will authenticate and give their consent to allow this app access to
// some resource they own.
app.get('/auth', function(req, res) {
  crypto.randomBytes(48, function(ex, buf) {
    var token = buf.toString('base64').replace(/\//g,'_').replace(/\+/g,'-');

    res.cookie('authstate', token);
    var authorizationUrl = createAuthorizationUrl(token);

    res.redirect(authorizationUrl);
  });
});

// After consent is granted AAD redirects here.  The ADAL library is invoked via the
// AuthenticationContext and retrieves an access token that can be used to access the
// user owned resource.
app.get('/getAToken', function(req, res) {
  if (req.cookies.authstate !== req.query.state) {
    res.send('error: state does not match');
  }
  var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);
  authenticationContext.acquireTokenWithAuthorizationCode(req.query.code, redirectUri, resource, sampleParameters.clientId, sampleParameters.clientSecret, function(err, response) {
    var message = '';
    if (err) {
      message = 'error: ' + err.message + '\n';
    }
    message += 'response: ' + JSON.stringify(response);

    if (err) {
      res.send(message);
      return;
    }

    // Later, if the access token is expired it can be refreshed.
    authenticationContext.acquireTokenWithRefreshToken(response.refreshToken, sampleParameters.clientId, sampleParameters.clientSecret, resource, function(refreshErr, refreshResponse) {
      if (refreshErr) {
        message += 'refreshError: ' + refreshErr.message + '\n';
      }
      message += 'refreshResponse: ' + JSON.stringify(refreshResponse);

      res.send(message); 
    }); 
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('listening on 3000');
```

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/blob/master/sample/website-sample.js

Comment: Your first config settings look similar to what I havee. But know I want to switch to multi-tenant. So I enabled this option in my Azure AD. But what changes do I have to make inside my config file? Only replacing `myTenant` with `common`? Because this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

As I known, I suggest you can follow the two documents below as references to get start.

1. Web App Sign In & Sign Out with Azure AD https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-openidconnect-nodejs/
2. Integrating Azure AD into a NodeJS web application https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-node-webapp-openidconnect/

For developing easier, you can try to use the node package `passport-azure-ad`(https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad) that is the one strategy of `passport` (http://passportjs.org/) for NodeJS to implement your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and able to resolve it. After googling i made two changes in config.js.

1. issuer value set to false.
2. responseMode value changed from query to form_post.

config.js :

```
exports.creds = {
    issuer : false,  
    realm : "<TENANT>",
    returnURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/openid/return',
    identityMetadata: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration', // For using Microsoft you should never need to change this.
    clientID: '<CLIENT_ID>',
    clientSecret: '<CLIENT_SECRET>', // if you are doing code or id_token code
    skipUserProfile: true, // for AzureAD should be set to true.
    responseType: 'id_token code', // for login only flows use id_token. For accessing resources use `id_token code`
    responseMode: 'form_post', // For login only flows we should have token passed back to us in a POST
 };
```